# findMeetingTimes endpoint in Graph API seems to not be accessible with app-only permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Can't get access to the findMeetingTimes endpoint in graph api.

I can list all users events, but when trying to use the findmeetingtimes endpoint
I'm getting "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.".

Is there a way to get access with app-only permissions?

or is it a bug? 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/559

Answer (score 0):

No, not at this time. This is in our backlog to enable, but it isn't working today. Unfortunately I can't give a timeline on this, but I'll update this answer once we turn it on.

Comment: ok, is there a work around, is it possible to use the Outlook Calendar REST API ? or does the same limitations apply?

Comment: No workarounds unfortunately. The Outlook API has the same limitation.

Comment: I'm experiencing this & a couple of other issues, I suppose it has not been updated yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it appears the restriction is still in place for Graph API (both v1.0 and beta) but this is not longer the case for Outlook Calendar REST API (v2.0).

In that you can use the following and get results
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{{any@yourdomain.com}}/findmeetingtimes

Whereas https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{any@yourdomain.com}}/findmeetingtimes still gives "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."